# Can't ping local computer on Macbook, but can on iPhone

Tags: macos, networking, lan

I have a computer on my network that I can reach from my iPhone (at the same IP), but my Macbook can't seem to be able to ping it. I have my firewall disabled on my Macbook, and I'm not sure what could cause this. All I have are guesses, and I figure someone else would know better.

Comment: Do you get IP from DHCP or assigned static IP address? You have Mac and iPhone. What else you have on the same network?

Comment: DHCP. I'm accessing everything over wifi. I also have a raspberry pi that I programmed as a relay to a router (by bridging the wifi and ethernet). So I guess I have a subnetowrk in my network, my main IPs are 192.168.1.*, and the sub is 0.*.

Comment: Is "can not ping" means you can not get respond from iphone when to ping? Did you check the ip configuration about assinged ip address and subnetmask on each device? I think you know you can not use same ip address to assgin. Did you check your DHCP server setting about reserved IP address, You should not use it if there is no special reason.

Comment: You were totally right. I forgot that I had a reservation on the subrouter, so it was causing it to try to assign a different address to a MAC address which already had an IP (the macbook). Thank you, this had been bugging me for a week now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please confirm as follows:

1. Check TCP/IP information on Mac and iPhone and whether same IP address is not in use or not.
2. Check DHCP server configuration such reserved IP address with MAC address, scope option and others.